# Disable IIS logging on individual MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, logging, iis-6

I have a few particular actions in a controller and I do not want IIS (6) to log the requests, but **only** on that particular controller.  I want it to log as normally for the rest of my site.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Curious, why would you want to omit only few? Is it getting big on size?

Comment: It's complicated, but I have to do a cross-domain ajax call using jsonp in a get request. That means I have to put my data in the querystring, which means I am transmitting sensitive info and don't want it logged.  For now I unchecked the query string in the logging but I'm still uneasy about it.  Storing this type of data comes with a hefty fine, so I'm trying to make absolutely sure that I can do these requests without the data being stored after the request is completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write a [custom logging module](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/174b0649-d1ab-4f25-bc8c-e6493a09b4d3.mspx?mfr=true) for this. By default it's all or nothing.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to get started with writing a custom logging module in C#.

Comment: @Josh, you may take a look at the following article on MSDN which contains a sample module written in C++: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259552