# How to prevent IIS 6 from logging certain requests (we bill for bandwidth and do not want our own traffic to count)?

Tags: iis, logging, iis-6

I wanted to find out if there is a way to have IIS 6 evalute logic/rules/criteria before writing a request to the IIS logs.  We bill for bandwidth and will have some processes that will check on/access the sites and we need to ensure the requests still go through, but we do not want them to appear in the customer's logs and count against their billing as we read the raw logs.

We use IIS 6, so suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  This seems like a problem people would have encountered before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

#### 1. Use a custom logging module

This question one is pretty much a duplicate (90%) of this one:

[Disable IIS logging on individual MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752513/disable-iis-logging-on-individual-mvc-controller)

Copy of the answer by Darin Dimitrov:

*You will need to write a [custom logging module](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/174b0649-d1ab-4f25-bc8c-e6493a09b4d3.mspx?mfr=true) for this. By default it's all or nothing.*

#### 2. Filter the log file

Another solution would be to just filter the log file or use a more advanced tool to generate the billing information. See e.g. here:

http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2010/03/25/analyze-your-iis-log-files-favorite-log-parser-queries.aspx